# Intel Euclid feature access from ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS-Euclid users,

Intel Euclid has everything builtin by default, but do I need to develop my own new ros nodes ?
How can I access all these nice features - any idea where to find examples or detailed specifications ?

Environmental sensors including inertial measurement unit, barometric pressure sensor, GPS, and proximity sensor

Audio:
Low Power, Dual I2S interface, Speaker 1W Mono

Microphone:
D-MIC, X3, Noise Cancellation

GPS:
GNS, GLONASS, Beidou, Galileo, QZSS, WAAS, EGNOS

The basic Euclid software contains pure samples for the camera and basic imu functions only.

Thanks for any hints from advanced Euclid users.

Cheers

Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269807/intel-euclid-feature-access-from-ros/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
I would try [Intel forums](http://www.euclidcommunity.intel.com/#support) for any questions regarding the Euclid itself. We can help you with ROS-related questions here, but anything else should go to the forums related to the specific platforms.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-09-03**:
Yes, you are completely right, but Intel forums are not very responsible about ros related drivers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found one hint only:

$sudo sensorhub_client -c list

A binary which is able to fetch some data from builtin sensors.

But no documentation for building own ros nodes which are able to use this data directly :-(

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0